# ¿cómo quito el am o pm de un datetime-local en html?

Tags: html

Tengo en un formulario en html un campo tipo `datetime-local` que se muestra asi: `dd/mm/aaaa 00:00 --:-- ----` , lo que quiero es que me aparezca sin el am o el pm asi: `dd/mm/aaaa 00:00 --:--` , el tipo date no me sirve por que solo me muestra para seleccionar la fecha `dd/mm/aaaa`

Comment: puedes agregar el contenido html para ver en que estas fallando, por favor.

Comment: actualmente html no tiene un atributo para formatear fechas por eso es que aveces hay que crear nuevos diseños y nos ayudan mucho los framework en estos casos te aconsejo busques uno

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta `datetime-local` es un elemento que no proporciona formatos, sino que el mismo toma el formato de tu navegador -> S.O del cliente.